# We get time from server and change into local time zone in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, nsdate, nsdateformatter

server time is 4:00AM and local current time is 3:32PM i was use this method but this method is not working so solve this.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:serverTime];
 NSLog(@"date : %@",date);

 NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
 NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

 NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
 NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
 NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

 NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:serverTime];
 NSLog(@"date : %@",date);

 NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
 NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

 NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
 NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
 NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

 NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"];
 [dateFormatters setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 [dateFormatters setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 [dateFormatters setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
 [dateFormatters setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
 serverTime = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];
 NSLog(@"DateString : %@", serverTime);"];
 [dateFormatters setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 [dateFormatters setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 [dateFormatters setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
 [dateFormatters setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
 serverTime = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];
 NSLog(@"DateString : %@", serverTime);
```

some people say this method is working but when i was use this code this is not working.

Comment: What?  What's not working?  Is it working or isn't it working?  If it isn't working, how is it not working?  Is it compiling?  Is it throwing an exception?  Is it displaying wrong results?  Is it melting your phone?

Comment: The posted code seems to have a copy and paste problem right in the middle after the 1st `dateFormatters` line.

Comment: I'm not up on iOS development, but this looks horrendously complicated for a simple timezone adjustment.

Comment: the time will not change into local timeZone we work on server app we get time from server and the server time is 4:00AM now we change into local timeZone of NewDelhi India.

Comment: Harjot, you didn't say anything you haven't already said.  Don't just tell us what's not happening.  Tell us what IS actually happening.

Comment: And fix the code. There is NO way the posted code even compiles.

Comment: Without knowing the time zone of the server you will never get correct results. Is the server's time zone fixed in API contract? If not, then you will need the server to send you not just the time but also include the time zone it is in.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSDate* NSdateFromNSString(NSString *selectedDate)
{
    NSString *dateWithInitialFormat =selectedDate;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Chicago"]];
    //Set Server ime zone

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateWithInitialFormat];
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should

```
dateFormatter.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

And

```
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```